# Access magento session vars in Codeigneiter

Tags: php, codeigniter, session-variables, magento-1.9, adminhtml

I am beginner in Magento. So may be this is not right question that magento supports this functionality or not. I am building a website structure with help of magento and codeigneiter on same environment. My requirement is get session details of magento in my framework so this is possible or not with magento + customization framework script.

Comment: php session is same for everything. you can make some wrapper function that will parse $_SESSION vars and returns values that you need.

Comment: I am not getting magento session by $_SESSION in my php function. I am also login from magento admin.

Answer (score 0):

Magento session is handled by the session class. set new variable and value in the session.

```
Mage::getSingleton("core/session")->setYourVariableName("your value here"); 
// set your own session variable name in CamelCase. 
//eg. you want to set author_name variable than use setAuthorName("value here")
```

I suggest you to go through refrence: https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html
and study about it well before paying with this.

Comment: But i am not getting session values in my php files.

Comment: Then how your Magento site is working, if you are not getting values in php code.

Comment: My php file is seperate by magento setup. In that file i want magento session variables also but this is not coming as i used print_r($_SESSION); not providing any thing.

Comment: This issue can take place due to privilege issues outside directory too. Check you .htaccess file for confirmation why you are not able to read session values outer php codes

Comment: htaccss file of magneto.

Comment: Yes the root directory will be having .htaccess file, where Magento is installed. Check is there any denies to access outside

Comment: are your CI and Magento or same domain?

Comment: I think so, he is using different directory areas or even different domains.